# Unable to generate log NLog internal logging file on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, logging, nlog, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I run websites and webjobs on Azure App Service and I want to enable NLog internal debugging to troubleshoot some logging problems.  In my NLog configuration code I do:

```
InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace;
InternalLogger.LogFile = "nlog.txt";
```

When run locally during development, `nlog.txt` shows up in the application binary directory (`bin`).  On Azure it does not show up.  Assuming perhaps a file system permissions issue I changed the code to:

```
InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace;
InternalLogger.LogFile = @"d:\logfiles\nlog.txt";
```

Azure App Service guarantees that the `d:\logfiles\` directory is writable.  Yet still no `nlog.txt` file.

Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to write to the directory `d:\logfiles\test.txt` from your application. Just to see if you application has proper permissions?

Comment: @Rolf Yes - I write all my log files there.

Comment: Make sure to configure the `InternalLogger` before creating any Logger-objects even the static ones that might exist in the Program.cs class.

Comment: Correction - I meant `d:\home\logfiles\`.  My code was correct but I wrote it incorrectly here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the `LogFiles` folder is under `D:\home` in Azure (you mentioned the file path is `d:\logfiles\`, so I also tried to create a `LogFiles` folder under `D:` drive directly, but an 500 internal server error occurs).

Please try to change the value to `d:\home\LogFiles\nlog.txt` for InternalLogger.LogFile, like `InternalLogger.LogFile= @"d:\home\LogFiles\nlog.txt"` .

I can see the nlog.txt generated in azure by using the following code:

```
 InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace;
 InternalLogger.LogFile = @"d:\home\LogFiles\nlog.txt";
 InternalLogger.Log(LogLevel.Trace, "a text message from here....");
```

You can refer to the pic below for test result.

[image]

Comment: My code was correct with `d:\home\logfiles\`; I just wrote it incorrectly here.  Oddly, I changed the path to `d:\local\temp\` which is writable space (but not recommended because the OS can wipe it at any time) and I was successful in writing the nlog internal logger file.  Which is seriously odd because d:\home\logfiles\ is exactly where nlog is writing the normal log files!

Comment: I stand corrected - my code was indeed wrong - I was pointing to the incorrect (read-only) location.  Oy...